# Determine whether the limit yields the derivative of a differentiable function f. Explain, use algebra to justify your conclusions.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Determine whether the limit yields the derivative of a differentiable function $f$. Explain, use algebra to justify your conclusions. $h$ approaches $0$ in all limits.

1. $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+2h)-f(x)}{2h}$
2. $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+2)-f(x)}{2h}$
3. $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$
4. $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$

Comment: What do you know about the derivative? Can you state the definition?

Comment: I know the definition of the derivative formula which is f(x+h)-f(x)/h. Im just not sure how to apply this to the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use algebra and variable substitutions to make each limit a limit of the form
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
Then it will be the derivative of $f(x)$. If it cannot be made to look like this, then it is not the derivative of $f(x)$. I will do the first one to show the concept, and leave the others as an exercise. We have $f(x+2h)$ and we want to have $f(x+h)$, so we substitute $h'=2h$. As $h\rightarrow0$, $h'=2h\rightarrow0$, so the limit becomes
$$\lim_{h'\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h')-f(x)}{h'}$$ which is the derivative of $f(x)$.

Comment: so for the second one, how would I do that because instead of f(x+h) it's f(x+2) and the denominator is 2h instead of 2

Answer (score 1):

For the second one, the numerator is constant with respect to h, so what we are looking at there is $$\lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{C}{2h}$$ which blows up and does not go to the derivative.

For the third, see comments on this reply. (This post has been edited)

The fourth one is what you gave as a definition of the derivative in a comment, so I'll leave that alone.

Comment: Your handling of third case is wrong. Given that $f$ is differentiable it does not mean that derivative $f'$ is continuous. But the conclusion in third case is true and can be proved in a different manner by adding subtracting $f(x) $ in numerator.

Comment: Doing as you say, $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)+f(x)-f(x-h)}{2h}=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{2h}+\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{2h}$ which would give you ($1/2$ of) the left and right limits of the derivative at x. To say that these are equal is to say that $f'$ is continuous at x.

Comment: The first fraction tends to $f'(x) /2$ and so does the second and on adding the desired limit is $f'(x) $. The question of left and right limits simply does not arise

Comment: The continuity of $f'$ on the other hand is based on the condition $\lim_{h\to 0}f'(x+h)=f'(x)$ and it can't be expressed solely in terms of original function $f$.

Comment: +1 for your update.